# Measuring Open Loop Gain

Tags: operational-amplifier, gain, loop-gain

I have a question about open loop gain. In the circuit below, I want to measure the open loop gain of the error op-amp. I'm curious if the Current Limiting op-amp will affect my gain.

What does it mean when they say Open loop voltage gain @ Rl = >= 10M, Change of Vo = 1v to 4v

[image]

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fTJSBL.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: Which controller chip is this diagram from?

Comment: http://www.microsemi.com/document-portal/doc_view/11119-sg1524b-datasheet

Comment: The gain should be roughly 1000, so my offset voltage between the + and - should be tiny?

Comment: You say you have a question but you don't say what it is. Don't be shy.

Comment: I didn't mean to be vague. My question is how do I measure the gain. It's Vo / V1 - V2 which should be 60db.. So I put a signal into the Error amp with a tiny offset?

Comment: For example. I'm currently putting in a signal of 3v in the + and 2.95V in the - of the error opamp @10hz. With that, I'm only getting .95v out so the gain is low.

Comment: To answer that comment we need a schematic. Use the schematic button on the editor tool bar. Show your chip power connections and how you are setting the voltages on the inputs. 0.95 V out sounds like the op-amp has reached negative supply.

Comment: I'm confused by how I need to set up the voltages and what they mean by the change in Vo.. I get the change in Vin as it's the difference between the two pins... Do I need to have different signals inputting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open loop gain is infinite high of an op-amp by design.
See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open-loop_gain Of course, in real opamps the gain can not be infinite, but it is quite high. In real opamps the output can not go to infinite high or low, but will be clipped by the min-max of voltage rails.

In the datasheet you can see an open loop gain of 78dB, which roughly corresponds to 100,000,000 times of amplification.

However, your circuit does not seem to be open-loop. It is a driver for a closed-loop system. The transistors drive the transformer, and there is a feedback from that fed to your error amplifier, this makes this circuit a closed loop control.

Comment: You're talking about the top circuit? How would one measure the open loop gain then.

Comment: So the spec says Open Loop voltage gain from Vo (1 to 4)v.. So I adjust my signal in Vdc till I see 1V out to 4V out and then Do 3V/Change in input?

Comment: I am unsure what are you willing to achieve. The top circuit says a 78dB open loop gain. A generic opamp like TL081 has similar open loop gain like 80dB. However the lower circuit makes no sense. The output of the opamp will be clipped by power supply rails, and you'll see a rail-to-rail square wave on the output.

Comment: Ignore that. I'm just trying to get the output working properly. I Currently have the senses tied low, and a input signal in with a 1mV Vdc Offset and I'm not seeing anything on the output.

Comment: So with the circuit I just updated, I'm getting a very large gain. Does that make sense?

Comment: Yes, this is how it is working. The gain is theoretically endless big, in practice it means 100,000,000 times of amplification. Therefore, it is pointless to use an opamp in an open-loop arrangement, since this amplification is a way too big to be anything useful. Opamps are used in a feedback arrangement, see http://www.ti.com/ww/en/bobpease/assets/AN-31.pdf for some basic use cases. Then you can use resistors to control the amplification of the circuit, instead of relying on the uselessly huge amplification of the opamp itself.

Comment: I'm trying to test it to the datasheet.. I'm currently on the Input Offset Voltage of the Current Sense Op amp.. Currently both inputs are tied to ground and I'm getting 2.2 V out, which is strange.

Answer (score 0):

Open loop gain [can be measured](http://www.analog.com/en/analog-dialogue/articles/simple-op-amp-measurements.html):

> When S1 and S2 are closed, Ios still flows in the 100-Ω resistors and
>   introduces an error in Vos, but unless Ios is large enough to produce
>   an error greater than 1% of the measured Vos it may usually be ignored
>   in this calculation.
>
> The open-loop dc gain of an op amp can be very high; gains greater
>   than 107 are not unknown, but values between 250,000 and 2,000,000 are
>   more usual. The dc gain is measured by forcing the output of the DUT
>   to move by a known amount (1 V in Figure 4, but 10 V if the device is
>   running on large enough supplies to allow this) by switching R5
>   between the DUT output and a 1-V reference with S6. If R5 is at +1 V,
>   then the DUT output must move to –1 V if the input of the auxiliary
>   amplifier is to remain unchanged near zero.

[image]